# If statement not triggering alert - form/quiz

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, alert

The script is supposed to bring a Javascript alert of a correct or incorrect answer, the alert is not popping up.  What could be the problem?  I have a feeling it's an easy fix I just can't seem to find it.  I've already validated the whole page (this is just a snippet) and it passed validation.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */

    function scoreQuestion1(answer){
    if (answer == "a")
       window.alert("Correct Answer");
    if (answer == "b")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "c")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "d")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    }
    function scoreQuestion2(answer){
    if (answer == "a")
       window.alert("InCorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "b")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "c")
       window.alert("Correct Answer");
    if (answer == "d")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    }
    function scoreQuestion3(answer){
    if (answer == "a")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "b")
       window.alert("Correct Answer");
    if (answer == "c")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "d")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");

    function scoreQuestion4(answer){
    if (answer == "a")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "b")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "c")
       window.alert("Correct Answer");
    if (answer == "d")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
     }  
    function scoreQuestion5(answer){
    if (answer == "a")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "b")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "c")
       window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
    if (answer == "d")
       window.alert("Correct Answer");
      } 


    </script>

</head>
<body>
                           <form action="" name="quiz">
                           <p><strong>1. How many natural elements are there?</strong></p><p>
                           <input type="radio" name="question1" value="a" onclick="scoreQuestion1('a')" />92<br />   <!-- correct answer-->
                           <input type="radio" name="question1" value="b" onclick="scoreQuestion1('b')" />113<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question1" value="c" onclick="scoreQuestion1('c')" />103<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question1" value="d" onclick="scoreQuestion1('d')" />88<br /></p>
                           <p><strong>2. If one kg of air is compressed from 1m3 to 0.5 m3, which of the following statements is true?</strong></p><p>
                           <input type="radio" name="question2" value="a" onclick="scoreQuestion2('a')" />The density is halved.<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question2" value="b" onclick="scoreQuestion2('b')" />The mass is halved.<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question2" value="c" onclick="scoreQuestion2('c')" />The density is doubled.<br />    <!--correct answer-->
                           <input type="radio" name="question2" value="d" onclick="scoreQuestion2('d')" />The mass is doubled.<br /></p>
                           <p><strong>3.  What is the acceleration due to gravity?</strong></p><p>
                           <input type="radio" name="question3" value="a" onclick="scoreQuestion3('a')" />980 m/s2<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question3" value="b" onclick="scoreQuestion3('b')" />9.8 m/s2<br />   <!--correct answer-->
                           <input type="radio" name="question3" value="c" onclick="scoreQuestion3('c')" />98 m/s2<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question3" value="d" onclick="scoreQuestion3('d')" />0.98 m/s2<br /></p>
                           <p><strong>4.  What is the SI unit of density?</strong></p><p>
                           <input type="radio" name="question4" value="a" onclick="scoreQuestion4('a')" />cm3/g<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question4" value="b" onclick="scoreQuestion4('b')" />m3/kg<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question4" value="c" onclick="scoreQuestion4('c')" />kg/m3<br />      <!--correct answer-->
                           <input type="radio" name="question4" value="d" onclick="scoreQuestion4('d')" />g/cm3<br /></p>
                           <p><strong>5.  Which of these has the highest density?</strong></p><p>
                           <input type="radio" name="question5" value="a" onclick="scoreQuestion5('a')" />Lead<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question5" value="b" onclick="scoreQuestion5('b')" />Water<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question5" value="c" onclick="scoreQuestion5('c')" />Mercury<br />
                           <input type="radio" name="question5" value="d" onclick="scoreQuestion5('d')" />Tungsten<br /></p>   <!--correct answer-->
                           </form>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. You'd be well to learn about arrays, your code would reduce dramatically!

Comment: Absolutely, I'm working my way through a javascript class and I'm trying to make sure I understand why things aren't working if something comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the function for scoreQuestion3, which results in a parse error. If you fix that, it should work.

```
function scoreQuestion3(answer){
if (answer == "a")
   window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
if (answer == "b")
   window.alert("Correct Answer");
if (answer == "c")
   window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
if (answer == "d")
   window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
}
```

[Working version at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DFEf/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, fresh eyes are the best.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing } to your scoreQuestion3.

A couple of things that you should look into learning though:

1) Proper indentation

If you indent whenever you decend a layer (as it were) it becomes much more obvious when these kind of errors occur.

```
function scoreQuestion3(answer){
  if (answer == "a")
    window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
  if (answer == "b")
    window.alert("Correct Answer");
  if (answer == "c")
    window.alert("Incorrect Answer");
  if (answer == "d")
    window.alert("Incorrect Answer");

  function scoreQuestion4()...
```

Immediately you can see that it's out of whack and adjust accordingly.

In something that kind of follows on directly from that:

2) Using the { brackets

```
if(answer=="a"){
  alert("Incorrect Answer");
}
```

Although you can omit them and the if statement will just use the next line, it becomes less clear.

3) Else

I imagine this is in your next lesson, but the code can be simplified hugely to:

```
function scoreQuestion3(answer){
  if(answer=="a"){
    alert("Correct Answer!");
  }else{
    alert("Incorrect answer I'm afraid!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ding ding ding.  Thank you very much.  My tired eyes didn't notice.